# Resume from suspend - Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: suspend, 17.10

I am using ubuntu 17.10 with gnome-shell 3.26. And many times, when I suspend my notebook by closing the cover and return it normally, I put my login and password and when I start using the applications it simply logoff. When I login again all applications are closed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can find the file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

The contents of my version look like this (although I'm on a desktop):

```
# ... Loads of comments ...

[Login]                                                                         
#NAutoVTs=6                                                                     
#ReserveVT=6                                                                    
#KillUserProcesses=no                                                           
#KillOnlyUsers=                                                                 
#KillExcludeUsers=root                                                          
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5                                                           
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff                                                        
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend                                                       
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate                                                   
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend                                                        
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore                                                   
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no                                                     
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no                                                   
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no                                                 
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes                                                   
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s                                                          
#IdleAction=ignore                                                              
#IdleActionSec=30min                                                            
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%                                                       
#RemoveIPC=yes                                                                  
#InhibitorsMax=8192                                                             
#SessionsMax=8192                                                               
#UserTasksMax=33%
```

Try changing the commented-out line
    #KillUserProcesses=no
by removing the leading '#'

I think this should prevent your computer from closing your apps when it suspends.

You' ll need to `sudo` to edit it.